# How to load icon image from server in google maps in swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uikit

I am working with Google maps.
this is my MapModel

```
struct MapModel: Codable {
    let iconUrl: String
    let xCoordinate: Double
    let yCoordinate: Double
}
```

I have- let marker = GMSMarker()
I want to set marker.icon from server using my model.
For loading image I use this extension.

```
extension UIImageView {
    func load(str: String) {
        let url = URL(string: str)
        if let url = url {
            self.load.request(with: url)
        } else {
            self.load(str: "imp.png")
        }
    }
}
```

But marker.icon is Uiimage type and this extension is for UIImageview. How can I get marker.icon?